# How feasible is it to setup a FreeNAS to be more like a full install of FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, freenas

So I've been playing with FreeNAS over the last week, finally trying to get my act together and store my important files properly.

I'm finding myself wanting to install and compile additional packages.

pkg_add has been great for some things, but it appears that my install is rather crippled.

1. make is missing. I installed gmake and linked make to that.
2. math.h is missing as is sys/cdefs.h I thought these are part of any core unix/linux system?
3. cc is missing though I've installed gcc45. I'm used to having just gcc. Sure I can create a link, but I'm not sure this is the proper thing to do.
4. perl installed fine, but I can't add stuff with cpan. This is how I discovered 1,2, and 3.

**So my question is this:** do I just need to bite the bullet and install a full FreeBSD? The web interface to FreeNAS is kinda nice

Comment: Are you running it as Embedded or Full Platform? http://freenas.org/faq:0011

Answer (score 1):

I know how frustrating and stressful this whole thing is!!

My alternative to this problem is to create a freebsd jail on top of freenas.

Then you're able to issue any commands you desire and can also link them together!

This is the simplest way I found so far to achieve this and it's awesome!
http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/freenas/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=8942

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1. I did this as well and it's great.